# Scrollbar no ng-view não funciona

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, rolamento

Galera, acontece o seguinte problema comigo: Estou fazendo uma aplicação web e estou utilizando o Angular.js como framework. Tenho uma div com ng-view e toda vez que carrega um página que necessita do scroll ele não aparece e a página fica pela metade. Porém de eu der um F5 o scroll aparece. Queria saber se alguém sabe como arrumar isso.

Desde já, obrigada!

Comment: Eu sugeriria adicionar alguns screenshots, assim como o código que envolve o ng-view. Fica um pouco difícil determinar as possíveis causas sem informações mais específicas.

Answer (score 0):

Vai no parent da sua ng-view e seta um width de acordo com o tamanho que você precisa e depois coloca a propriedade overflow:scroll;